# how to loop a single string JSON

Tags: jquery, json

how can I loop through this JSOn object and get the data in an unordered list like

.fnem  anam  1

.ynem  snam  2

.onem  dnam  3

```
{"uname":["fnem,ynem,onem"],"Oname":["anam,snam,dnam"],"osize":["1,2,3"]}
```

for more clarity,this is the source of that result:

```
echo json_encode(array('uname'=>$_POST['Oname'],'Oname'=>$_POST['uname'],'osize'=>$_POST['size']));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `["fnem","ynem","onem"]` ? Otherwise what's the array for?

Comment: Why do you have arrays of just a single string? Why not make the values separate elements of the array?

Comment: Mr.Roko,that is exactly what i have seen on my browser as the responsefrom Json.but if you can give me your solution as regards your option ,you're wellcome

Comment: Mr.Barmar,that is why I also need your solution on how i should do that.please send it up

Comment: If you want to send a comment to someone, put `@` before their name. SO doesn't recognize `Mr.`, so it doesn't notify them.

Comment: See ArsenMkrt's answer, it's how I would do it.

Comment: @Barmar...OK.Sir .lets get the ball rolling then

Answer (score 0):

```
var mobject = {"uname":["fnem,ynem,onem"],"Oname":["anam,snam,dnam"],"osize":["1,2,3"]} 
for(var topV in mobject)
{
   mobject[topV] = mobject.split();
}
for(var value in mobject.uname){
    console.log(mobject.uname[value],mobject.Oname[value],mobject.osize[value]);
}
```

jquery version:

```
$.each(mobject,function(index,value){
    mobject[index] = mobject.split();
})

$.each(mobject.uname,function(index,value){
    console.log(mobject.uname[index],mobject.Oname[index],mobject.osize[index]);
})
```

Comment: You're not splitting the values on commas.

Comment: @Barmar I read so fast and I thought that uname , oname, osize are arrays. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Mr.Barmar, please let me see your option,it is important

Comment: could you also varry it with jquery' .each()

Comment: @user3253289 I updated the answer with jquery .each() method also

Answer (score 0):

```
var jObject = {
"uname": ["fnem, ynem, onem"],
"Oname": ["anam, snam, dnam"],
"osize": ["1, 2, 3"]
};
var sunames = jObject.uname[0].split(",");
var sonames = jObject.Oname[0].split(",");
var sosizes = jObject.osize[0].split(",");

for(var i = 0; i < sunames.length; i++)
{
    console.log(sunames[i] + ' ' + sonames[i] + ' ' + sosizes[i]);
}
```

Comment: issue here is uname.length is 1 as it contains only one string "fnem,ynem,onem".

Comment: oops, I didn't noticed that arrays are single element... I don't think there is any reason to keep array as a string...

Comment: @ArsenMkrt could you provide a jquery version

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var data = {
    "uname": ["fnem,ynem,onem"],
    "Oname": ["anam,snam,dnam"],
    "osize": ["1,2,3"]
};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var str="";
    for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            str+=" "+data[property][0].split(',')[i];
        }
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

[Here is demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6Vw6u/)

Comment: Depending on the order that properties will be visited by `for-in` seems like a bad idea.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the'll be processed in a particular order.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521410/stringify-an-js-object-in-asc-order I assume JSON.stringify is internally looping over the properties, and he's running into cases where it reorders them.

Comment: but in this question json stringify is not the issue?  OP has given json string and he ask how to iterate.

Comment: Internally, stringify presumably has a loop similar to yours. And that loop doesn't get the elements in the order that the programmer put them. Javascript object properties are not ordered, and you shouldn't depend on them to remember the order they were entered.